# How to open and close files properly in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, file, c++11, unix

I want to open some files, redirect the output of them and then go back to previous situation, so I wrote:

```
int fd = open("test.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666);
dup(1);
dup2(3, 1);
close(3);
//call my func() to print in std::cout which will write to test.txt
dup2(4, 1);//Close file
```

I know that the default input channel is in index 0, output channel (screen) in index 1 and `stderr` in index 2 so `fd` will get 3, `dup` 1 will create another pointer to output channel in index 4, then I replace screen with my file and close that isn't needed.

1. My code is correct, but did I forget anything else or can it be made shorter/ more clear?
2. **Most importantly**, in case one line fails I want to return false but this will be a lot of checks and in every advance step we need to close more. How can I solve this problem?

What if I wanted in case of failure to make everything go back to default situation?

**Please Note,** I **only** know and want to use `open,close,dup,dup2`

Comment: It would be very simple for someone to run your program in such a manner that the initial `open()` will return 5. Or 6. or 19. Hillarity ensues. You cannot assume what the newly-opened file descriptor will be until you have much, much more controls in place.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik my professor said open will return the least unused index which is 3 in my case

Comment: As I explained, I can easily run your program in such a way that the first open file descriptor can be anything. You wouldn't be the first one that shows evidence, on Stackoverflow, that their professor is incompetent.

Comment: There are four main bullets  about what makes a bad programmer: 1) ignoring diagnostics of compiler  2) writing code that doesn't do error checking 3) inventing and reinventing a wheel instead of using (approved by employer) tools and libraries  4) declining to educate self and learn use most appropriate tools ("I don't know how to use axe, so I'll be using hammer. How I can make hammer cut?" - jokes on me here, though, there are hammers with blades -chipping hammers).

Answer (score 2):

**Most importantly** it is the duty of a programmer to write reliable, faultless code, and this includes thorough error checking. Error checking often makes for large parts of the code, especially when user interaction is part of the program. But, there is no way around it, if you want to be/become a good programmer.

That said, it is easy (in a first step) to change your code so that it does *not* depend on specific file descriptor numbers (not tested).

```
int fileFd; 
int redirectFd1;
int redirectFd2;

fileFd = open( "test.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666 );
redirectFd1 = dup( 1 );
redirectFd2 = dup2( fileFd, 1 );
close( fileFd );

//call my func() to print in std::cout which will write to test.txt

dup2( redirectFd1, 1 );//Close file
```

Next step is to add error checking.

```
int fileFd; 
int redirectFd1;
int redirectFd2;

if ( ( fileFd = open( "test.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666 ) ) == -1 ) {
    // open() failed. Do appropriate error handling here...
    exit( 1 );
}

if ( ( redirectFd1 = dup( 1 ) ) == -1 ) {
    // dup() failed. Do appropriate error handling here...
    // Since we arrvied here, fileFd *is* open. So we need to close it.
    // But redirectFd1 is *not* open
    close( fileFd );
    exit(1);
}

if ( ( redirectFd2 = dup2( fileFD, 1 ) ) == -1 ) {
    // dup() failed. Do appropriate error handling here...
    // Since we arrvied here, fileFd *and* redirectFd1 *are* open. 
    // So we need to close them.
    // But redirectFd2 is *not* open
    close( fileFd );
    close( redirectFd1 );
    exit(1);
}

close( fileFd ); 

//call my func() to print in std::cout which will write to test.txt

if ( dup2( redirectFD1, 1 ) == -1 ) {
    // dup2() failed. Do appropriate error handling here...
    close( redirectFd1 );
}

close( redirectFd1 );
```

One can argue whether checking for errors on the `close( fileFd )` statement is needed or nor. Fact is that `open()` succeeded, so it would be very unsusual for `close()` to fail here. One can also argue whether checking for errors on the last `dup2()` is needed or not.

In general, I keep track of open files, and take care of closing in case of errros in a clean-up routine. The code might look like this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


int  fileFd; 
bool fileFdIsOpen = false;

int  redirectFd1;
bool redirectFd1IsOpen = false;

int  redirectFd2;
bool redirectFd2IsOpen = false;

void cleanup();


int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {

    int stdoutFd = fileno( stdout );
    
    if ( ( fileFd = open( "test.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666 ) ) == -1 ) {
        // open() failed. Do appropriate error handling here...
        exit( 1 );
    }

    fileFdIsOpen = true;

    if ( ( redirectFd1 = dup( stdoutFd ) ) == -1 ) {
        // dup() failed. Do appropriate error handling here...
        cleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    redirectFd1IsOpen = true;

    if ( ( redirectFd2 = dup2( fileFd, stdoutFd ) ) == -1 ) {
        // dup() failed. Do appropriate error handling here...
        cleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    redirectFd2IsOpen = true;
    close( fileFd ); 
    fileFdIsOpen = false;

    //call my func() to print in std::cout which will write to test.txt

    if ( dup2( redirectFd1, stdoutFd ) == -1 ) {
        // dup2() failed. Do appropriate error handling here...
        cleanup();
    }

cleanup();
exit (0);

}

void cleanup() {
    if ( fileFdIsOpen ) {
        close( fileFd );
        fileFdIsOpen = false;
    }
    
    if ( redirectFd1IsOpen ) {
        close( redirectFd1 );
        redirectFd1IsOpen = false;
    }
    
    if ( redirectFd2IsOpen ) {
        close( redirectFd2 );
        redirectFd2IsOpen = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry but I think your code won't work, in case the first open faild why are u closing default output stream even though I need it later?

Comment: Plus, you forgot to do:close of  redirectFd1

Comment: I don't close default output stream. I added some comment to the error path. *Note* the `exit(1);` inside the if-then. The program stops after an error has occurred.

Comment: Closing `redirectFd1` at the end of the program doesn't hurt anything. The program is gone and the kernel will cleanup anyway, including closing open file descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that default input channel is in index 0, output channel
> (screen) in index 1 and stderr in index 2 so fd will get 3

That's undetermined, process can be run in away those ids would be altered and starting descriptor also might be different from stderr+1. Theremore, on Linux there are situation where process can be created with none open, but that's different.

In C header `<stdio.h>` defines those variables that are supposed to be initialized by runtime library.

```
   extern FILE *stdin;
   extern FILE *stdout;
   extern FILE *stderr;
```

Code you had shown is pretty much C code, not C++, but you can use `<cstdio>` and `fileno` function to obtain descriptor

```
   int fileno(FILE *stream);
```

You have to check returned results of `fileno`, `dup` and `open` to be sure that you program didn't run into some limitations imposed on it, and `errno` variable would tell you a reason. On some other platforms, like Windows, more appropriate  error reporting functions do exist.